Unlock SIM PIN with wwapi on Windows
I want to unlock a SIM card and get the WwanIntfOpcodeGetRadioInfo status with the wwapi.dll but I get the error 87 (wrong parameter).
I use LoadLibrary because I have no references / documentation.
Following the steps I have tried.

Open Handle (successful)
 HANDLE hWwan = NULL;
 DWORD dwVersion;  
 HRESULT hr = 0;  
 hr = pWwanOpenHandle(WWAN_API_VERSION_2_0, NULL, &dwVersion, &hWwan)   
 ...


Enumerate interfaces (successful) I get the values: Interfaces: 1 || Device: Generic Mobile Broadband Adapter #18 || State: 6
  PWWAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST pIfList = NULL;
  hr = WwanEnumerateInterfaces(hWwan, NULL, &pIfList);
  ...


Get radio info (failed, error 1780 Nullptr). The equivalent WwanIntfOpcodeRadioState to set the state, works.
  WWAN_RADIO_STATE radioState = { WwanRadioOff, WwanRadioOff };
  hr = WwanSetInterface(
  hWwan,
  &pIfList->InterfaceInfo[0].InterfaceGuid,
  WwanIntfOpcodeGetRadioInfo,
  0,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  &radioState,
  NULL
  );


Unlock PIN (failed, error 87 wrong parameters)
pinAction.PinType = WwanPinTypePin1;   
pinAction.PinOperation = WwanPinOperationEnter;  
wcscpy(pinAction.Pin, L"1234\0");  

hr = WwanSetInterface(  
hWwan,  
&pIfList->InterfaceInfo[0].InterfaceGuid,  
WwanIntfOpcodePin,  
sizeof(pinAction),  
&pinAction,   
NULL,   
NULL,   
NULL  
);




If some functions are undocumented, that's for a (good) reason. Any attempt to bypass that, even if it looks like a neat hack is actually a lame workaround, and might stop working randomly. Where did you het those signatures? Check [SO]: How do I ask a good question? or
[SO]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))
for more asking related details.
